# Hexagonal phenocrysts with a metallic luster?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, rocks, igneous, hydrothermal-vents

I recently realized that I am surrounded by interesting rocks. Having no background in geology nor geologist friends, I rely on online resources to navigate the intriguing stuff I stumble across. But Google lens can only get you so far.

I have many questions. The rocks attracting my attention are, I think, mostly intrusive igneous rocks with white and black phenocrysts and/or porphyritic structure. Often there are also shiny metallic bits mixed in (sulfides?).

For the present post, I focus on two rocks I found 350 km apart from each other and a difference of 700m in elevation (see attached images). In both of these rocks, it seems to me there are shiny metallic bits among the phenocrysts that have a hexagonal shape. Please have a look at the attached pictures and let me know 1) if you agree that the shiny metallic bits are roughly hexagonal in shape; and 2) what the geological explanation behind the hexagonal shapes might be.

The hexagonal metallic shape in the first image is a little above and to the right of the big white rectangular quartz phenocryst. Hexagonal metallic shape number 2 is a little above and to the left of the center of the second image. I took both images using my digital microscope at about 10x-20x magnification.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]